# link on random image background

Tags: javascript, random, background, hyperlink, onclick

I have this code to have random background images, I need to make sure that when someone clicks on the picture to open a web page, one for each image. Can you help me please?
this is the code:

```
</head><body onLoad="LoadRandomBackground(); StartBackgroundRefreshTimer()">
</body>
</head>
<body onLoad="LoadRandomBackground()">
</body>


<script type="text/javascript">

var bgImages = [];
bgImages[1]="/img/sfondi/bg-stanem.jpg";
bgImages[2]="/img/sfondi/booking.jpg";


function LoadRandomBackground()
{
var randomImageIndex = Math.floor(Math.random()*bgImages.length)
document.body.background  = bgImages[randomImageIndex];

}

function StartBackgroundRefreshTimer()
{
var timer = setInterval('LoadRandomBackground()',1000); // millisecondi
}



</script>
```

thank's

can someone help me?

Comment: What problem are you encountering?

Comment: I do not know how to add the link when someone clicks on an image. Each image must lead to a different link

Answer (score 0):

you could create a second array ...

```
  var bgImagesUrls=[];
```

then assign the urls to the array using the same indexes for the bgImages

you could then place in LoadRandomBackground

```
   document.<someelement>.href=bgImagesUrls[randomImageIndex];
```

Comment: thank's for reply but if i create second array it give me a white page without background. this is the link I think I'm doing something wrong. http://transfer.stanem.it/

Answer (score 0):

Here a short possible script  http://jsfiddle.net/d2Dmh/3/

```
bgImages[0]= {url: ...
```

here you can place the url you want as destination as another parameter (destination : "url")

And with

```
window.location = "http://www.google.com/";
```

you can navigate to the new page in the document click function.

You need jquery for my example.

Comment: thank's for reply but if i test the script it give me a white page without background. this is the link I think I'm doing something wrong. http://transfer.stanem.it/index%20-%20Copia.php